# How to subtract a date from current date after converting the date into ISO format in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have a document where I have to get the number of days between two dates. Below is the document :-

```
{
  "appId": "f6e9f71c-d1b6-45c1-a2f3-e5b3a668646c",
  "dueDate": "23/5/2023"
}
```

I wanted to get the difference between **current date** and the **dueDate**. So my current date will be in ISO format. Any idea how to convert the dueDate into ISO format so that I can subtract and get the remaining days

I have tried the below query...

```
SELECT (DATE_FORMAT_STR(date_add_str(now_str(), 0, "day"), '%d/%m/%Y') - attributes.dueDate) 
AS remainingDays
FROM workflow_update WHERE appId="f6e9f71c-d1b6-45c1-a2f3-e5b3a668646c";
```

Result :-

```
{ "remainingDays": null }
```

Expected Result :-

```
{ "remainingDays": 48 }
```

Assuming **current date is = 10-07-2023**

Any leads will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`DATE_DIFF_MILLIS` or `DATE_DIFF_STR`](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/datefun.html) for getting the difference between two dates. Here's an example (I've just hardcoded the dates in the `SELECT` via `LET`):

```
SELECT
  todaysDate,
  earlierDate,
  DATE_DIFF_MILLIS(earlierDate, todaysDate, 'day') AS remainingDays

LET
  todaysDateParse = DATE_FORMAT_STR(date_add_str(now_str(), 0, "day"), '%d/%m/%Y'),
  todaysDate = STR_TO_MILLIS(todaysDateParse, "DD/MM/YYYY"),
  earlierDate = STR_TO_MILLIS("23/5/2023", "DD/MM/YYYY")
```

This outputs:

```
[
  {
    "earlierDate": 1684800000000,
    "remainingDays": -48,
    "todaysDate": 1688947200000
  }
]
```

If you want a positive number, you can flip the arguments around in `DATE_DIFF_MILLIS`.

Some notes:

- I'm actually not clear on the difference between "%d/%m/%Y" and "DD/MM/YYYY", so you may want to double check that. As far as I can tell, using "DD/MM/YYYY" is correct, but I could be wrong.
- You can probably also simplify your `DATE_FORMAT_STR` line to `DATE_FORMAT_STR(now_str(), '%d/%m/%Y')`, since you are just adding 0, but I assume you had that there for a reason, so I left it in my example.